# How to set header and options in axios?

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I use Axios to perform an HTTP post like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
params = {'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': self.language}
headers = {'header1': value}
axios.post(url, params, headers)
```

Is this correct? Or should I do:

```js
axios.post(url, params: params, headers: headers)
```

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Answer (score 592):

There are several ways to do this:

- For a single request:

  ```
  let config = {
    headers: {
      header1: value,
    }
  }

  let data = {
    'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': self.language
  }

  axios.post(URL, data, config).then(...)
  ```
- For setting default global config:

  ```
  axios.defaults.headers.post['header1'] = 'value' // for POST requests
  axios.defaults.headers.common['header1'] = 'value' // for all requests
  ```
- For setting as default on axios instance:

  ```
  let instance = axios.create({
    headers: {
      post: {        // can be common or any other method
        header1: 'value1'
      }
    }
  })

  //- or after instance has been created
  instance.defaults.headers.post['header1'] = 'value'

  //- or before a request is made
  // using Interceptors
  instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers.post['header1'] = 'value';
    return config;
  });
  ```

Answer (score 321):

> You can send a get request with Headers (for authentication with jwt for example):

```
axios.get('https://example.com/getSomething', {
 headers: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token //the token is a variable which holds the token
 }
})
```

> Also you can send a post request.

```
axios.post('https://example.com/postSomething', {
 email: varEmail, //varEmail is a variable which holds the email
 password: varPassword
},
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + varToken
  }
})
```

> My way of doing it,is to set a request like this:

```
 axios({
  method: 'post', //you can set what request you want to be
  url: 'https://example.com/request',
  data: {id: varID},
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + varToken
  }
})
```

Comment: You second post request does not provide specific headers, can you edit it  for full example ?

Comment: by using `data` in interceptors.request => it will override your actuall body part from the specific call which where we are using. So not used in such case.

Comment: Do you have to follow this standard of 'Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token' or can you do something like Auth: token for example? I'm not using auth0 api but doing my own in node, sorry if stupid question new to jwt and security stuff in general

Answer (score 104):

```js
axios.post('url', {"body":data}, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I was confusing whether ```header``` is declared in singular or plural. From your answer, this helped me.

Answer (score 40):

You can pass a config object to axios like:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '....',
  params: {'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': self.language},
  headers: {'header1': value}
})
```

Answer (score 27):

Here is the Right way:-

```js
axios.post('url', {"body":data}, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 24):

This is a simple example of a configuration with headers and responseType:

```
var config = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  responseType: 'blob'
};

axios.post('http://YOUR_URL', this.data, config)
  .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Content-Type can be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'application/json'
and it may work also 'application/json;charset=utf-8'

responseType can be 'arraybuffer', 'blob', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'

In this example, this.data is the data you want to send. It can be a value or an Array. (If you want to send an object you'll probably have to serialize it)

Comment: Can you explain the difference between setting the headers with our without the config keyword?

Comment: Using a config variable generates a nicer and more readable code; nothing else @bubble-cord

Answer (score 19):

You can initialize a default header `axios.defaults.headers`

```
 axios.defaults.headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'myspecialpassword'
    }

   axios.post('https://myapi.com', { data: "hello world" })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Response', response.data)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log('Error: ', e.response.data)
        })
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also set selected headers to every `axios` request:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'AUTH_TOKEN';
    return config;
});
```

Second method

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'AUTH_TOKEN';
```

Answer (score 16):

if you want to do a get request with params and headers.

```js
var params = {
  paramName1: paramValue1,
  paramName2: paramValue2
}

var headers = {
  headerName1: headerValue1,
  headerName2: headerValue2
}

 Axios.get(url, {params, headers} ).then(res =>{
  console.log(res.data.representation);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

try this code

in example code use axios get rest API.

in mounted

```
  mounted(){
    var config = {
    headers: { 
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': '5156f83861mshd5c5731412d4c5fp18132ejsn8ae65e661a54' 
      }
   };
   axios.get('https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats? 
    country=Thailand',  config)
    .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}
```

Hope is help.

Answer (score 8):

**I have face this issue in post request**. I have changed like this in axios header. It works fine.

```
axios.post('http://localhost/M-Experience/resources/GETrends.php',
      {
        firstName: this.name
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      });
```

Answer (score 6):

I had to create a `fd=new FormData()` object and use the `[.append()][1]` method before sending it through axios to my Django API, otherwise I receive a 400 error.
In my backend the profile image is related through a OneToOne relationship to the user model. Therefore it is serialized as a nested object and expects this for the put request to work.

All changes to the state within the frontend are done with the `this.setState` method. I believe important part is the handleSubmit method at the end.

First my axios put request:

```
export const PutUser=(data)=>(dispatch,getState)=>{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    dispatch({type: AUTH_USER_LOADING});                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    const token=getState().auth.token;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    axios(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ¦ method:'put',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ¦ url:`https://<xyz>/api/account/user/`,                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ¦ data:data,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ¦ headers:{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    ¦ ¦ Authorization: 'Token '+token||null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ¦ ¦ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ¦ }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ¦ .then(response=>{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ¦ ¦ dispatch({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ¦ ¦ ¦ type: AUTH_USER_PUT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ¦ ¦ ¦ payload: response.data,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ¦ ¦ });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ¦ })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ¦ .catch(err=>{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ¦ ¦ dispatch({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ¦ ¦ ¦ type:AUTH_USER_PUT_ERROR,                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ¦ ¦ ¦ payload: err,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ¦ ¦ });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ¦ })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }
```

My handleSubmit method needs to create the following json object, where the image attribute gets replaced by the actual user input:

```
user:{
username:'charly',
first_name:'charly',
last_name:'brown',
profile:{
image: 'imgurl',
  }
}
```

Here is my handleSumit method inside the component:
check [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```
handleSubmit=(e)=>{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
¦ e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
¦ let fd=new FormData();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
¦ fd.append('username',this.state.username);                                                                                                                                                                                                             
¦ fd.append('first_name',this.state.first_name);                                                                                                                                                                                                         
¦ fd.append('last_name',this.state.last_name);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
¦ if(this.state.image!=null){fd.append('profile.image',this.state.image, this.state.image.name)};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
¦ this.props.PutUser(fd);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Async/Await

> Axios post signature
>
> post(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse>
> Both data and config are Optional
>
> AxiosRequestConfig can be looked at - https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/e462973a4b23e9541efe3e64ca120ae9111a6ad8/index.d.ts#L60

```
 ....
 ....
 try {
   ....
   ....
   const url = "your post url"
   const data = {
     HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE: self.language
   }
   const config = {
      headers: {
       "header1": value
      },
      timeout: 1000,
      // plenty more options can be added, refer source link above
    }

   const response = await axios.post(url, data, config);
   // If Everything's OK, make use of the response data
   const responseData = response.data;
   ....
   ....
 }catch(err){
   // handle the error
   if(axios.isAxiosError(err){
     ....
     ....
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated',
  params: {page: '2', per_page: '40'},
  headers: {Authorization: '_authkey_'}
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use params and body together in a request with axios.

```
  sendAllData (data) {
        axios
        .post(API_URL + "receiveData", JSON.stringify(data), {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
          params: { mail: xyx@example.col }, //Add mail as a param
        })
        .then((response) => console.log("repsonse", response.status)); 
  }
```

Answer (score -9):

@user2950593
Your axios request is correct. You need to allow your custom headers on server side.
If you have your api in php then this code will work for you.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");   
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, header1");
```

Once you will allow your custom headers on server side, your axios requests will start working fine.

Comment: The OP was asking for nodejs, not php though , just saying