# How to add headers to an Axios call in VueJS?

Tags: ajax, curl, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have the HTTP call in php code:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlForTheCallGoesHere);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

Which I now need to convert it to convert to [VueJS Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) call.
What I know so far, is that a Axious calls can be created as:

```
  axios.get(urlForTheCallGoesHere)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(responseData)
      //do something with the responseData
    })
    .catch(errorData => {
      console.log(errorData)
      //do something with the errorData
    })
  }
```

I'm aware that custom params to the call can be added like this (an example):

```
  axios.post(exampleUrlForSomeRegistrationLink, {
    email: "exampleEmail@gmail.com",
    password: "examplePassword"
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(responseData)
    //do something with the responseData
  }).catch(errorData => {
    console.log(errorData)
    //do something with the errorData
  })
```

And also I'm aware that requests/responses can be manipulated (for example in *main.js* entry file) with assigning a default values or with interceptors:

```
//using default values
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://changeTheUrlForTheCallExample.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'exampleValue';
axios.defaults.headers.get['Accepts'] = 'application/json';

//using interceptors
const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  console.log('Request Interceptor', config)
  return config
})
const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
  console.log('Response Interceptor', res)
  return res
})
```

But with all of the above, I am still not sure how to convert the php code to VueJS code (using Axios). The main problem is **how to add the values for the options** CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER **as above**?

Comment: Hi! If your problem is to pass url prom PHP to JS as variable, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24834434/9021949

Comment: Well for the browser `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` are the default behavior. The browser follows redirects and always verifies the servers ssl-certificate (if the request is done over HTTPS). Also as you seen the data is returned from the server so the  `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is also satisfied. If you have a problem with your call then it's somewhere else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @vstm what I was actually asking was, is there any way to set these values via (for example) headers in the call? Since I know how to set the headers, but not sure which headers should be set.