# Axios instance for API call body payload ( creating the common object for all API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, axios

I am using Axios for the API call, here I have created the instance for a common header in each and every API call(authorization things).

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'demo API'
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    config.headers['testkey'] = 'randomdata'

  return config
}, function (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

now for calling

```
return axiosInstance.post('/api/demo, {myCommonBody})
  .then(data => {
   //action and action..
 })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });
```

Here all I have to pass `myCommonBody` in all API body.

But such things I need to be common from the interceptor as well (alike in the header I did).

So whenever we call any API with common API instance, here we get the BODY part by default.

Any lead appreciates for the answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: why you are using intercepters?

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581882/3170628

Comment: @Alserda I am talking about the body part here, and while `interceptors.request` in config.data here our actual body part will get override with the common instance. So not used in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    config.headers['testkey'] = 'randomdata'

    config.data = Object.assign({}, config.data, {myCommonBody});

  return config
}, function (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

or

```js
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'demo API',
  data: {myCommonBody}
})
```

Comment: ```config.data = {...config.data, ...{"key": "value"}}``` same things with spread operator rocks!

Answer (score 0):

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'demo API',
  data: {'myCommonBody': 'myCommonBodyDetails')
})
```

And all set for every api call.