# How to use axios instead of fetch in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I use fetch to send data to webservice. How can I do this with axios ?*

```
 fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
            }),
             body: JSON.stringify(object)
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data) code that is close to what you want.

```
 axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'myurl',
    data: bodyFormData,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Alternately, you can set you configuration then use  `axois.post()`. [This](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) axios cheatsheat may help you as well.

Comment: what should I give to data ?  object   ?

Comment: Yes that is where you data will go. You can also do axios.post(URL, Object); Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios) link for more info.

Comment: @hakan did this answer your question?

Comment: Oh thx bro yes it is ! . I have one more question can u help me about that please ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991655/how-to-send-base64-code-to-webservice-webservice