# axios how to send windows authentication headers to API

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I have an API deployed to the server. Authentication is set to "Windows Authentication" but when I send a request using `axios` it returns

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

How can I send a request with the headers for windows authentication?

```
axios.get('http://ir-devtestsvr/FantasticDashboard/api/p/getDataA')
     .then(r=>{
       this.data = r.data
       if(typeof(cb)== 'function'){
         cb()
       }
     })
```

can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Refer to axios docs or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 401 is a challenge to authenticate, the server or proxy is saying, to access to this resource you need to authenticated it should also tell you what authentication schemes it supports

for example for Windows its either Kerberos / NTLM or both 
If you view the response in Fiddler or another HTTP inspector you should see at least one of the 2 below, that's a good starting point

- WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
- WWW-Authenticate: NTLM

Your browser should then send another request automatically with the token for example like this [image] from [this](https://techblog.mediaservice.net/2017/05/fiddler-ntlm-authentication-when-burp-suite-fails/) site

Once your site is setup in IIS and you have ticked Windows authentication, you should not need to do anything else, unless there is a config issue, your proxy or your web server needs looking at.

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) for an explanation of how the 401 challenge works
see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication/) for a windows auth headers & flow
see [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication) & [here](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Configuring-Firefox-for-Integrated-Windows-Authentication) for how chrome & firefox implement

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `withCredentials` property of the [Axios Request Config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) to `true` the default value is `false`.

> `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests
> should be made using credentials

**Example:**

```js
axios({
    method: "get",
    url,
    responseType: "json",
    withCredentials: true,
});
```