# API header parameters returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am working a small webapp to teach myself some gcloud and js. currently am trying to send a get request from a google cloud function using axios to a web api.  any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

the web api needs the following parameters in the header
Accept:application/json
APIKey: APIKEY

I've been trying to use the code in [How to set header and options in axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios)
and axios info, but I keep getting errors (SyntaxError: Unexpected token)

Index.JS currently looks like so

```
const axios = require("axios");

exports.run = async(req, res) => {

    axios.get('APIURL', {
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json';
       'APIKey': 'KEY'
     }
    }).then((response) => {
        res.status(200).send(response.data);
        console.log(response);
      }, (error) => {
        res.status(500).send(response.data);
        console.log(error);
      });

     };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_NAME",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full error message, and indicate which line of code it's referring to.

Comment: Typo: You used a `;` where you should have used a `,`

Answer (score 3):

This is not a valid JSON object:

```
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json';
       'APIKey': 'KEY'
     }
```

The semicolon is out of place.  Use a comma instead:

```
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'APIKey': 'KEY'
     }
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON either. Property names must be strings, not identifiers and strings must be quoted with double, not single, quotes.

Comment: … and looking at the context, [it isn't supposed to be JSON anyway](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs!

I could have sworn I had a comma there. I did format the code in notepad before creating this post so I may have just typed it in afterwards. sorry for the confusion

But I double checked everything, still getting errors, my issue is that am not sure how to pass header info...and first time using java, a lot of new things but jumping in head first.

Error Looks like so
Error: function terminated. Function cannot be initialized.