# How to pass dynamic parameters to axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I was just reading a css-tricks article on how to make you're API request DRY using axios [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/stay-dry-using-axios-for-api-requests/). Now reacting something like this would work fine :

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://mysite/v3',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

The thing is what if i want to pass additional parameters to this instance ? I.E. i have another parameter that i would like to the header like so:

```
'X-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN': sessionToken,
```

Also what if i have multiple other options to pass to the header ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set header and options in axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios)

Comment: @Dan not extactly , i need to pass the `X-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN': sessionToken,` dynamically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass `headers` dynamically, you could export a function that takes `options` as an argument and returns a new instance of `axios`:

```js
// utils/custom-axios.js

export default function(options = {}) {
  const { 
    headers = {} 
  } = options;
  
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://mysite/v3",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      ...headers
    }
  });
}
```

Then you could use it the following way:

```js
const axios = require("./utils/custom-axios");

const options = { 
  headers: { "X-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN": "secret" } 
};

axios(options)
  .post("./user.json", formData)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);

// alternatively, don't pass any options 
axios()
  .post("./user.json", formData)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Comment: this is more of what i was looking for , had tried something similar , let me try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right you want to pass headers for distinct calls instead of having them set for all requests using the base configuration?

What about `axios.get('url', { headers: 'X-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN': sessionToken })` ?

Comment: Hi thanks , this does't seem to work though , don't get any error in the console too.

Comment: How do you determine that it does not work? Did you check the actual request that is sent?