# Reactjs : Header in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im trying to send an header with a email to my API , but my API always receive a `body{headers:{email:xxx`

my code in the client is like this :

```
export const envmailesqueci = async (
  credentials,
  setFieldError,
  setSubmitting
) => {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:3003/users/forgotpassword",{headers:
        {email:credentials.email}
      }  
).then((response) => {
        setSubmitting(false);
```

How can I change it to send a header instead of a header inside of the body ?

Comment: You should pass headers in the third property
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a null as the second parameter

```
await axios
      .post(url, null, {headers:
        {email:credentials.email}
      }
```

[axios#post(url[, data[, config]])](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1)

Comment: that was it , wich kind of things I can insert in this second parameter ?

Comment: See the link, the 2nd param is http body data