# Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'. Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a get method, when i run the code i'm getting this **Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.**. I have tried to set headers. Here is my code.

```
<template>
   <div class="container">
     <button @click="SearchTown"> Search Town </button>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
        name: 'SearchTown',
        props: {
            messege: String
        },
  data(){
    return{
      search: [],
    }
    
    },

  methods :{
      SearchTown() {
    axios
      .get('https://david.darwinist.io/proxy/5000/town/',{headers:{'content-type':'application/json'}})
     .then((response) => {// checking response in the console
            console.log(response.data)})
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
 }
}

</script>
```

I'm having 400 error code. I need help.

This is my backend code

```
def getTown(session, town_dict):
    try:
        town = (
            session.query(Town)
            .join(Town.county)
            .join(County.nation)
            .where(County.name == town_dict["county"])
            .where(Town.name == town_dict["name"])
            ).one()
        town_county = copy.copy(town).__dict__
        del town_county["_sa_instance_state"]
        town_county["county"] = town.county.name
        town_county["nation"] = town.county.nation.name
        return town_county
    except MultipleResultsFound:
        return "bad Gateway!", 502
    except NoResultFound:
        return "Results not found!", 404
```

I'm not really sure if i have to change my query. Kindly advice.

Comment: you should add the content-type in the response headers, i don't know python so i can not tell you how to do that

Comment: @Lk77 which response header? can you edit it for me? thank you. Because i know it wrong to put headers in the url for get request. T hank you

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-139638284) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754473/17089665), they might be of help. It seems you have to have data filled with something in order for the header to not be automatically discarded.

Comment: Just in case someone is using a `RequestParser` from Python `flask-restx` dependency, set the `location` parameter in the `add_argument` function. If not, it'll raise that error

Answer (score 3):

As commented in this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-136505548

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-139638284

**Your GET request must have some data passed along it.** `data: {}` should do the trick.

Some people find it kind of misleading. The explanation for this behaviour is [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-311788525):

> Content-Type describes what format the request data is in. If there is no request data, there is no need to specify the Content-Type.

Comment: i think the correct header is `Accept: application/json` not `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: It might be, although [it seems this 'issue' also affects the `Accept` header](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-405930811)

Comment: thank you @S.Dre i will take a look at them

Comment: Please let us know if it solved your issue!

Comment: @S.Dre i did manage, i had to modify the backend, i was validating data in the backend, i had to get ```get``` method out of validation. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For my application this was a breaking change from werkzeug [v2.3.0](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#version-230)

for accepting without application/json header I use flask and werkzeug v2.0.3